# How to use greater than and smaller than in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am currently doing a project and I have to do a criteria where all the records have to be shown for a sales table which I have made. Now the goal is that it needs to be greater than 25000 and smaller than 35000 but don't know how to do it

Comment: " it needs to be greater then 25000 and smaller then 35000" What is "it"?

Comment: It is of a datatype Currency

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
where [salesfield] > 25000 and [salesfield] < 35000
```

Comment: Is this going to function this code ?                                                SELECT Sales.SalespersonID, Sales.[First Name Sales], Sales.[Surname Sales], Sales.[Department Number], Sales.Customer, Sales.[Zip Code], Sales.[Annual Sales]
FROM Sales
WHERE (((Sales.[Annual Sales])<=2500)) OR (((Sales.[Annual Sales])>=3500));

Comment: It will "work" but will return a different result than your original question. But why don't you just try? It will take you some minutes while receiving comments here can take a day. And in the end, you will have to work with this yourself.